picamera2: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
I am trying to apply object detection and tracking from what I learned in a tutorial (in the tutorial it was a still camera recording a highway with cars), and apply it to my PiCam Module 3. I have the camera running but I can't seem to get the .read command to work with the array my camera creates, because of the error in the title.
I was expecting the code in which I draw a bounding rectangle and ID around a moving object to apply to each frame captured in the array of my Picam, but the code gives me an error after the first line. Do I need to install the numpy library for my Picam array? I didn't need it for the tutorial tracking.
Here is the working code from the tutorial:
import cv2
from tracker import *

# Create tracker object
tracker = EuclideanDistTracker()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("highway.mp4")

# Object detection from Stable camera
object_detector = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=100, varThreshold=40)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = frame.shape

    # Extract Region of interest
    roi = frame[340: 720,500: 800]

    # 1. Object Detection
    mask = object_detector.apply(roi)
    _, mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    detections = []
    for cnt in contours:
        # Calculate area and remove small elements
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area > 100:
            #cv2.drawContours(roi, [cnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)


            detections.append([x, y, w, h])

    # 2. Object Tracking
    boxes_ids = tracker.update(detections)
    for box_id in boxes_ids:
        x, y, w, h, id = box_id
        cv2.putText(roi, str(id), (x, y - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(roi, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

    cv2.imshow("roi", roi)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)

    key = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

And here is all of my code:
import cv2
from tracker import *
from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview
import time
#Create tracker object
tracker = EuclideanDistTracker()
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture("highway.mp4")
#below is untitled stuff but cant save 
picam2 = Picamera2()
camera_config = picam2.create_still_configuration(main={"size": (1920, 1080)}, lores={"size": (1920, 1080)}, display="lores")
picam2.configure(camera_config)
#picam2.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)
picam2.start()
#time.sleep(2)
#while True:
   # cap = picam2.capture.array()
    
   # cv2.imshow("Camera", cap)
   # cv2.waitKey(45)
# Object detection from stable camera
object_detector = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=100, varThreshold=40)

while True:
    cap = picam2.capture_array()
    cv2.imshow("Camera", cap)
    cv2.waitKey(45)
    
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = frame.shape
    #print(height,width) - Can use this command to see the height and width of your frame? So potentially the camera?
    #Extract region of interest
    roi = frame[0: 1920,0: 1080]
    #Object Detection
    mask = object_detector.apply(roi)
    _, mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    detections = []
    for cnt in contours:
        #Calculate area and remove small elements
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area > 100:
            #cv2.drawContours(roi, [cnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            detections.append([x, y, w, h])
    #Object tracking
    boxes_ids = tracker.update(detections)
    for box_id in boxes_ids:
        x, y, w, h, id = box_id
        cv2.putText(roi, str(id), (x, y - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(roi, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
        
    
    print(detections)
    cv2.imshow("roi", roi)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
    key = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if key == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Error code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ryanplato/Tutorial Image Tracking.py", line 28, in <module>
    ret, frame = cap.read()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'


Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

You seem to be assuming that picam2.capture_array returns exactly the same thing as cv2.VideoCapture.  That's totally unjustified.  Have you read the documentation to figure out how to read from picam2?

@TimRoberts It seems I have not read enough lol. I am very very new to python and am doing this for a school project. I will read up on how to read from picam2.

voting to close as a typo. this is a simple logic error. you're calling a method on something that doesn't have the method.
